# clear recent app list programatically

Tags: java, android, android-recents, recent-screens

I am trying to develop "Recent Apps Kill" App. I am able to show the recent running apps. But I am not able to kill all running apps(which shown in recent task list).

I have tried/read:

```
 1. android:excludeFromRecents="true"
 2. android:noHistory= "true"
```

but these are for only current app(or same user id apps) not for other apps.

```
3. android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);//doesn't removed from recent list

4. activitymanager.killBackgroundProcesses(procInfos.get(pnum).processName);// not working
```

Comment: So you're actively trying to reduce battery life? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91888/how-to-close-all-background-apps-at-once-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: but i am trying it for learning purpose.. what about toddler lock app/Recent App Cleaner - Xposed?

Comment: I know those apps exist. If it's only a learning experience, I am sure I've seen over links mentioning the lines you have that "don't work"